# Opensource alternative to Sessionbox Chrome extension

Tags: web-apps, chrome, web-browser

Is there an opensource alternative to [`Sessionbox`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig) Chrome extension to manage multiple login sessions?